# Auto complete text view should show list when @ clicked

Tags: android, filter, autocompletetextview

I have one requirement in my App. I am using auto complete text view. But I want to display my items when user entered "@" and once user enter " @" then entire list should display and if "@Y" enters then filter should start working. How ca I achieve this.

```
AutoCompleteTextView txtSearch;  
     List<People> mList;
    PeopleAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mList = retrievePeople();
        txtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
        txtSearch.setThreshold(1);
        adapter = new PeopleAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.lbl_name, mList);


          // txtSearch.setAdapter(adapter);

        txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                int occurrences = 0;
               if (txtSearch.getText().toString().endsWith("@")){
                   txtSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });


    }

    private List<People> retrievePeople() {
        List<People> list = new ArrayList<People>();
        list.add(new People("James", "Bond", 1));
        list.add(new People("Jason", "Bourne", 2));
        list.add(new People("Ethan", "Hunt", 3));
        list.add(new People("Sherlock", "Holmes", 4));
        list.add(new People("David", "Beckham", 5));
        list.add(new People("Bryan", "Adams", 6));
        list.add(new People("Arjen", "Robben", 7));
        list.add(new People("Van", "Persie", 8));
        list.add(new People("Zinedine", "Zidane", 9));
        list.add(new People("Luis", "Figo", 10));
        list.add(new People("John", "Watson", 11));
        return list;

    }
```

This is my code.If i am using text chnage listner nnothing is happening. If i am  removing that that list is displaying always if it contains related characters. I want to achieve like exactly whats app group tagging
  Please help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you set "@" prefix when user start typing and let it work in a normal way ?

Comment: means setting prefix to the items in the list?

Comment: Then try with custom-filter and make appropriate search condition as per your need.

Comment: txtSearch.getText().toString().contains("@")

Comment: or try  s.eqauls("@")

Comment: I tried like this         if (txtSearch.getText().toString().contains("@")){
            txtSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

Comment: and also in xml of autocomplete textview android:completionThreshold="1"

Comment: yes its there in xml and in code also that line was there @Vij

Comment: yes there and check

Comment: i already gave Threshold

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147429/discussion-between-vij-and-yamuna).